# Ejabberd APIs not working with python requests

Tags: python-requests, xmpp, ejabberd, ejabberd-api, ejabberd-auth

I'm using ejabberd from the docker container. I followed [this link](https://www.process-one.net/blog/install-ejabberd-on-windows-10-using-docker-desktop/) to install ejabberd docker container.

I tried the Administration APIs in the [docs](https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/ejabberd-api/admin-api/). For example, I have tried to register users with API in postman. It worked and created the user in the server. But when I tried to send a post request with the python requests library, I get 401 error.

My *ejabberd.yml* file:

```
###
###              ejabberd configuration file
###
### The parameters used in this configuration file are explained at
###
###       https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration
###
### The configuration file is written in YAML.
### *******************************************************
### *******           !!! WARNING !!!               *******
### *******     YAML IS INDENTATION SENSITIVE       *******
### ******* MAKE SURE YOU INDENT SECTIONS CORRECTLY *******
### *******************************************************
### Refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML for the brief description.
###

hosts:
  - localhost

loglevel: 4
log_rotate_size: 10485760
log_rotate_date: ""
log_rotate_count: 1
log_rate_limit: 100

certfiles:
  - /home/ejabberd/conf/server.pem

ca_file: "/home/ejabberd/conf/cacert.pem"

## When using let's encrypt to generate certificates
##certfiles:
##  - /etc/letsencrypt/live/localhost/fullchain.pem
##  - /etc/letsencrypt/live/localhost/privkey.pem
##
##ca_file: "/etc/letsencrypt/live/localhost/fullchain.pem"

listen:
  -
    port: 5222
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_c2s
    max_stanza_size: 262144
    shaper: c2s_shaper
    access: c2s
    starttls_required: true
  -
    port: 5269
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_s2s_in
    max_stanza_size: 524288
  -
    port: 5443
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    tls: true
    request_handlers:
      "/admin": ejabberd_web_admin
      "/api": mod_http_api
      "/bosh": mod_bosh
      "/captcha": ejabberd_captcha
      "/upload": mod_http_upload
      "/ws": ejabberd_http_ws
      "/oauth": ejabberd_oauth
  -
    port: 5280
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    request_handlers:
      "/admin": ejabberd_web_admin
  -
    port: 5281
    module: ejabberd_http
    ip: 127.0.0.1
    request_handlers:
      /api: mod_http_api
  -
    port: 1883
    ip: "::"
    module: mod_mqtt
    backlog: 1000

  
  ##
  ## https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/#stun-and-turn
  ## ejabberd_stun: Handles STUN Binding requests
  ##
  ##-
  ##  port: 3478
  ##  ip: "0.0.0.0"
  ##  transport: udp
  ##  module: ejabberd_stun
  ##  use_turn: true
  ##  turn_ip: "{{ IP }}"
  ##  auth_type: user
  ##  auth_realm: "example.com"
  ##-
  ##  port: 3478
  ##  ip: "0.0.0.0"
  ##  module: ejabberd_stun
  ##  use_turn: true
  ##  turn_ip: "{{ IP }}"
  ##  auth_type: user
  ##  auth_realm: "example.com"
  ##- 
  ##  port: 5349
  ##  ip: "0.0.0.0"
  ##  module: ejabberd_stun
  ##  certfile: "/home/ejabberd/conf/server.pem"
  ##  tls: true
  ##  use_turn: true
  ##  turn_ip: "{{ IP }}"
  ##  auth_type: user
  ##  auth_realm: "example.com"
  ##
  ## https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/#sip
  ## To handle SIP (VOIP) requests:
  ##
  ##-
  ##  port: 5060
  ##  ip: "0.0.0.0"
  ##  transport: udp
  ##  module: ejabberd_sip
  ##-
  ##  port: 5060
  ##  ip: "0.0.0.0"
  ##  module: ejabberd_sip
  ##-
  ##  port: 5061
  ##  ip: "0.0.0.0"
  ##  module: ejabberd_sip
  ##  tls: true

s2s_use_starttls: optional

acl:
  local:
    user_regexp: ""
  loopback:
    ip:
      - 127.0.0.0/8
      - ::1/128
      - ::FFFF:127.0.0.1/128
  admin:
    user:
      - "admin@localhost"
  apicommands:
    user: 
      - "admin@localhost"

access_rules:
  local:
    allow: local
  c2s:
    deny: blocked
    allow: all
  announce:
    allow: admin
  configure:
    allow: admin
  muc_create:
    allow: local
  pubsub_createnode:
    allow: local
  trusted_network:
    allow: loopback

api_permissions:
  "API used from localhost allows all calls":
    who:
      ip: 127.0.0.1/8
    what:
      - "*"
      - "!stop"
      - "!start"
  "console commands":
    from:
      - ejabberd_ctl
    who: all
    what: "*"
  "admin access":
    who:
      access:
        allow:
          acl: loopback
          acl: admin
      oauth:
        scope: "ejabberd:admin"
        access:
          allow:
            acl: loopback
            acl: admin
    what:
      - "*"
      - "!stop"
      - "!start"
  "public commands":
    who:
      ip: 127.0.0.1/8
    what:
      - status
      - connected_users_number
  "some playing":
    from:
      - ejabberd_ctl
      - mod_http_api
    who:
      acl: apicommands
    what: "*"

shaper:
  normal: 1000
  fast: 50000

shaper_rules:
  max_user_sessions: 10
  max_user_offline_messages:
    5000: admin
    100: all
  c2s_shaper:
    none: admin
    normal: all
  s2s_shaper: fast

max_fsm_queue: 10000

acme:
   contact: "mailto:example-admin@example.com"
   ca_url: "https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"

modules:
  mod_adhoc: {}
  mod_admin_extra: {}
  mod_announce:
    access: announce
  mod_avatar: {}
  mod_blocking: {}
  mod_bosh: {}
  mod_caps: {}
  mod_carboncopy: {}
  mod_client_state: {}
  mod_configure: {}
  mod_disco: {}
  mod_fail2ban: {}
  mod_http_api: {}
  mod_http_upload:
    put_url: https://@HOST@:5443/upload
  mod_last: {}
  mod_mam:
    ## Mnesia is limited to 2GB, better to use an SQL backend
    ## For small servers SQLite is a good fit and is very easy
    ## to configure. Uncomment this when you have SQL configured:
    ## db_type: sql
    assume_mam_usage: true
    default: never
  mod_mqtt: {}
  mod_muc:
    access:
      - allow
    access_admin:
      - allow: admin
    access_create: muc_create
    access_persistent: muc_create
    access_mam:
      - allow
    default_room_options:
      allow_subscription: true  # enable MucSub
      mam: false
  mod_muc_admin: {}
  mod_offline:
    access_max_user_messages: max_user_offline_messages
  mod_ping: {}
  mod_privacy: {}
  mod_private: {}
  mod_proxy65:
    access: local
    max_connections: 5
  mod_pubsub:
    access_createnode: pubsub_createnode
    plugins:
      - flat
      - pep
    force_node_config:
      ## Avoid buggy clients to make their bookmarks public
      storage:bookmarks:
        access_model: whitelist
  mod_push: {}
  mod_push_keepalive: {}
  mod_register:
    ## Only accept registration requests from the "trusted"
    ## network (see access_rules section above).
    ## Think twice before enabling registration from any
    ## address. See the Jabber SPAM Manifesto for details:
    ## https://github.com/ge0rg/jabber-spam-fighting-manifesto
    ip_access: trusted_network
  mod_roster:
    versioning: true
  mod_sip: {}
  mod_s2s_dialback: {}
  mod_shared_roster: {}
  mod_stream_mgmt:
    resend_on_timeout: if_offline
  mod_vcard: {}
  mod_vcard_xupdate: {}
  mod_version:
    show_os: false

### Local Variables:
### mode: yaml
### End:
### vim: set filetype=yaml tabstop=8
```

I tried to create user with POSTMAN and its working.

[image: regsiter API tried with POSTMAN]

But, when I tried to create it with requests library, its not working.

*api.py*

```
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth


url = "http://localhost:5443/api/register"
data = {
    "user": "testuser2",
    "host": "localhost",
    "password": "password"
}

# res = requests.post(url, json=data, auth=("admin", "admin_password"))

res = requests.post(url, json=data, auth=HTTPBasicAuth("admin", "root"))

print(res)
```

The response when I run the above script:

```
<Response [401]>
```

I have admin user in the server with the same credentials that I passed to the auth attribute of the post method.
I'm new to XMPP and I'm not sure what I'm missing here.
I'm using the latest version of ejabberd docker container. I have disabled SSL while using POSTMAN.

Comment: Use `res = requests.post(url, json=data, auth=HTTPBasicAuth("admin@localhost", "root"))`, and let me know the result.

Comment: or `res = requests.post(url, json=data, auth=("admin@localhost", "root"))`

Comment: Yeah. It worked. I realized it when I checked the Authentication tab in the POSTMAN. Btw, Thanks man. Now, I need to focus on creating APIs. Probably I'll come here again with some other errors :)

Comment: Sure. Should I post it as an answer so you can accept it? or should skip it? Generally, questions should have an answer, so it can help people looking for it after clarification through comments.

Comment: Yeah. It will be good to have an answer.

Comment: Well, I see we got a better answer.

Comment: ha ha. someone is late to the party but still steals it. A good answer though.

Comment: Well, he is the core developer & maintainer of `ejabberd`. If anyone can give the best answer on this topic, it's him. Upvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full process, with all the steps that you must do, or ensure are correctly done:

Register the account "admin@localhost":

```
ejabberdctl register admin localhost somepass
```

Add the "admin@localhost" account to the "admin" ACL:

```yaml
acl:
  admin:
    user:
      - "admin@localhost"
```

Allow the "admin" ACL to perform "register" API calls:

```yaml
api_permissions:
  "admin access":
    who:
      access:
        allow:
          - acl: admin
    what:
      - "register"
```

In your query,  set the account JID and password, not only the account username:

```py
res = requests.post(url, json=data, auth=HTTPBasicAuth("admin@localhost", "somepass"))
```

Now run your program:

```
$ python3 api.py
<Response [200]>
```

Check the account was registered:

```
$ ejabberdctl registered_users localhost
admin
testuser2
```

If you to register an account that already exists, it will response 409:

```
$ python3 api.py
<Response [409]>
```

Comment: My API is working now. I can able to create users. But I can't create room with `create_room` API but it return 0 (which means success as mentioned in the documentation). If I check my server there is no any new rooms created. I have also posted a question about this.

Comment: Ok, let's look at the create_room problem in its specific post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73004508/cant-able-to-create-a-room-in-ejabberd-through-rest-api