# Can't able to create a room in ejabberd through REST API

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, ejabberd-api

I'm trying to create a room in ejabberd with REST API.

I'm using `/create_room` API to create room as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/ejabberd-api/admin-api/#create-room).

When I tried to hit the API, I receive the response as `0` which means success (as mentioned in the documentation).

When I checked the list of rooms in Pidgin or in Admin interface, I didn't see any new rooms created.

When I try to delete the room with `destroy_room` API, It says, Room not available.

Data I send with `create_room` API:

```
{
  "name": "room1",
  "service": "conference.localhost",
  "host": "localhost"
}
```

My ejabberd.yml file:

```
###
###              ejabberd configuration file
###
### The parameters used in this configuration file are explained at
###
###       https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration
###
### The configuration file is written in YAML.
### *******************************************************
### *******           !!! WARNING !!!               *******
### *******     YAML IS INDENTATION SENSITIVE       *******
### ******* MAKE SURE YOU INDENT SECTIONS CORRECTLY *******
### *******************************************************
### Refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML for the brief description.
###

hosts:
  - localhost

loglevel: 4
log_rotate_size: 10485760
log_rotate_date: ""
log_rotate_count: 1
log_rate_limit: 100

certfiles:
  - /home/ejabberd/conf/server.pem
  
ca_file: "/home/ejabberd/conf/cacert.pem"

## When using let's encrypt to generate certificates
##certfiles:
##  - /etc/letsencrypt/live/localhost/fullchain.pem
##  - /etc/letsencrypt/live/localhost/privkey.pem
##
##ca_file: "/etc/letsencrypt/live/localhost/fullchain.pem"

listen:
  -
    port: 5222
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_c2s
    max_stanza_size: 262144
    shaper: c2s_shaper
    access: c2s
    starttls_required: true
  -
    port: 5269
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_s2s_in
    max_stanza_size: 524288
  -
    port: 5443
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    tls: false
    request_handlers:
      "/admin": ejabberd_web_admin
      "/api": mod_http_api
      "/bosh": mod_bosh
      "/captcha": ejabberd_captcha
      "/upload": mod_http_upload
      "/ws": ejabberd_http_ws
      "/oauth": ejabberd_oauth
  -
    port: 5280
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    request_handlers:
      "/admin": ejabberd_web_admin
  -
    port: 5281
    module: ejabberd_http
    ip: 127.0.0.1
    request_handlers:
      /api: mod_http_api
  -
    port: 1883
    ip: "::"
    module: mod_mqtt
    backlog: 1000

  
  ##
  ## https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/#stun-and-turn
  ## ejabberd_stun: Handles STUN Binding requests
  ##
  ##-
  ##  port: 3478
  ##  ip: "0.0.0.0"
  ##  transport: udp
  ##  module: ejabberd_stun
  ##  use_turn: true
  ##  turn_ip: "{{ IP }}"
  ##  auth_type: user
  ##  auth_realm: "example.com"
  ##-
  ##  port: 3478
  ##  ip: "0.0.0.0"
  ##  module: ejabberd_stun
  ##  use_turn: true
  ##  turn_ip: "{{ IP }}"
  ##  auth_type: user
  ##  auth_realm: "example.com"
  ##- 
  ##  port: 5349
  ##  ip: "0.0.0.0"
  ##  module: ejabberd_stun
  ##  certfile: "/home/ejabberd/conf/server.pem"
  ##  tls: true
  ##  use_turn: true
  ##  turn_ip: "{{ IP }}"
  ##  auth_type: user
  ##  auth_realm: "example.com"
  ##
  ## https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/#sip
  ## To handle SIP (VOIP) requests:
  ##
  ##-
  ##  port: 5060
  ##  ip: "0.0.0.0"
  ##  transport: udp
  ##  module: ejabberd_sip
  ##-
  ##  port: 5060
  ##  ip: "0.0.0.0"
  ##  module: ejabberd_sip
  ##-
  ##  port: 5061
  ##  ip: "0.0.0.0"
  ##  module: ejabberd_sip
  ##  tls: true

s2s_use_starttls: optional

acl:
  local:
    user_regexp: ""
  loopback:
    ip:
      - 127.0.0.0/8
      - ::1/128
      - ::FFFF:127.0.0.1/128
  admin:
    user:
      - "admin@localhost"
  apicommands:
    user: 
      - "admin@localhost"

access_rules:
  local:
    allow: local
  c2s:
    deny: blocked
    allow: all
  announce:
    allow: admin
  configure:
    allow: admin
  muc_create:
    allow: local
  pubsub_createnode:
    allow: local
  trusted_network:
    allow: loopback

api_permissions:
  "API used from localhost allows all calls":
    who:
      ip: 127.0.0.1/8
    what:
      - "*"
      - "!stop"
      - "!start"
  "console commands":
    from:
      - ejabberd_ctl
    who: all
    what: "*"
  "admin access":
    who:
      access:
        allow:
          acl: loopback
          acl: admin
      oauth:
        scope: "ejabberd:admin"
        access:
          allow:
            acl: loopback
            acl: admin
    what:
      - "*"
      - "!stop"
      - "!start"
  "public commands":
    who:
      ip: 127.0.0.1/8
    what:
      - status
      - connected_users_number
  "some playing":
    from:
      - ejabberd_ctl
      - mod_http_api
    who:
      acl: apicommands
    what: "*"

shaper:
  normal: 1000
  fast: 50000

shaper_rules:
  max_user_sessions: 10
  max_user_offline_messages:
    5000: admin
    100: all
  c2s_shaper:
    none: admin
    normal: all
  s2s_shaper: fast

max_fsm_queue: 10000

acme:
   contact: "mailto:example-admin@example.com"
   ca_url: "https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"

modules:
  mod_adhoc: {}
  mod_admin_extra: {}
  mod_announce:
    access: announce
  mod_avatar: {}
  mod_blocking: {}
  mod_bosh: {}
  mod_caps: {}
  mod_carboncopy: {}
  mod_client_state: {}
  mod_configure: {}
  mod_disco: {}
  mod_fail2ban: {}
  mod_http_api: {}
  mod_http_upload:
    put_url: https://@HOST@:5443/upload
  mod_last: {}
  mod_mam:
    ## Mnesia is limited to 2GB, better to use an SQL backend
    ## For small servers SQLite is a good fit and is very easy
    ## to configure. Uncomment this when you have SQL configured:
    ## db_type: sql
    assume_mam_usage: true
    default: never
  mod_mqtt: {}
  mod_muc:
    access:
      - allow
    access_admin:
      - allow: admin
    access_create: muc_create
    access_persistent: muc_create
    access_mam:
      - allow
    default_room_options:
      allow_subscription: true  # enable MucSub
      mam: false
  mod_muc_admin: {}
  mod_offline:
    access_max_user_messages: max_user_offline_messages
  mod_ping: {}
  mod_privacy: {}
  mod_private: {}
  mod_proxy65:
    access: local
    max_connections: 5
  mod_pubsub:
    access_createnode: pubsub_createnode
    plugins:
      - flat
      - pep
    force_node_config:
      ## Avoid buggy clients to make their bookmarks public
      storage:bookmarks:
        access_model: whitelist
  mod_push: {}
  mod_push_keepalive: {}
  mod_register:
    ## Only accept registration requests from the "trusted"
    ## network (see access_rules section above).
    ## Think twice before enabling registration from any
    ## address. See the Jabber SPAM Manifesto for details:
    ## https://github.com/ge0rg/jabber-spam-fighting-manifesto
    ip_access: trusted_network
  mod_roster:
    versioning: true
  mod_sip: {}
  mod_s2s_dialback: {}
  mod_shared_roster: {}
  mod_stream_mgmt:
    resend_on_timeout: if_offline
  mod_vcard: {}
  mod_vcard_xupdate: {}
  mod_version:
    show_os: false

### Local Variables:
### mode: yaml
### End:
### vim: set filetype=yaml tabstop=8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a configuration similar to yours. I didn't care to set exactly the same, because the problem I imagine is that you create room with default options, that means, a temporary room: if it has no occupants, it is destroyed a few seconds later.

I use this script:

```py
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

url = "http://localhost:5280/api/create_room"
data = {
    "name": "room1",
    "service": "conference.localhost",
    "host": "localhost"
}
res = requests.post(url, json=data, auth=HTTPBasicAuth("admin@localhost", "asd"))
print(res)
```

Create the room and check it exists:

```bash
$ python3 create-room.py
<Response [200]>

$ ejabberdctl muc_online_rooms conference.localhost
room1@conference.localhost
```

The ejabberd log file shows the API query, and 30 seconds later the room is destroyed due to inactivity:

```
2022-07-18 11:53:05.327862+02:00 [info] (<0.1317.0>) Accepted connection [::1]:43856 -> [::1]:5280
2022-07-18 11:53:05.328232+02:00 [info] API call create_room [{<<"name">>,<<"room1">>},
                      {<<"service">>,<<"conference.localhost">>},
                      {<<"host">>,<<"localhost">>}] from ::1:43856

2022-07-18 11:53:35.329246+02:00 [info] Destroyed MUC room room1@conference.localhost because it's temporary and empty
2022-07-18 11:53:35.330000+02:00 [info] Stopping MUC room room1@conference.localhost
```

If you now check the list of online rooms, there is none now:

```bash
$ ejabberdctl muc_online_rooms conference.localhost
$
```

There are three solutions:

A) When creating a room, it's temporary by default, join some occupant before it gets destroyed (30 seconds)

B) Configure in `ejabberd.yml` that mod_muc rooms newly created are persistent by default:

```yaml
modules:
  mod_muc:
    default_room_options:
      persistent: true
```

C) When creating a room, configure it to be persistent:

```py
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

url = "http://localhost:5280/api/create_room_with_opts"
data = {
    "name": "room1",
    "service": "conference.localhost",
    "host": "localhost",
    "options": [{
        "name": "persistent",
        "value": "true",
        }]
}
res = requests.post(url, json=data, auth=HTTPBasicAuth("admin@localhost", "asd"))
print(res)
```